# how organize canvas script in template

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

How can I separate a canvas script into a helper? At the moment it only works if it is written right into the template itself. I guess it's trivial – but I cannot find how to do it. Thanks! (scaledSprite is a helper as well)

```
<template name="spriteBox">
    <script>
        var myImage = new Image();
        myImage.src="{{ spirte.url store='OriginalPix' }}";

        myImage.onload = function() {
            var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
            var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
            ctx.fillStyle = "{{ sprite.metadata.backColor }}";
            ctx.fillRect(0, 0, {{ scaledSprite.widthDevice }}, {{ scaledSprite.heightDevice }});
            ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
            ctx.drawImage(myImage, 0, 0, {{ scaledSprite.widthDevice }}, {{ scaledSprite.heightDevice }});
        }
    </script>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="{{ scaledSprite.widthDevice }}" height="{{ scaledSprite.heightDevice }}" style="width:{{ scaledSprite.width }}px; height: {{ scaledSprite.height }}px;">
        This browser does not support HTML5 canvas
    </canvas>
</template>
```

**THIS IS NOT WORKING:**
**Trying to separate the script and move it to spriteBox.js:**

```
Template.spriteBox.rendered = function () {
    var myImage = new Image();
    myImage.src= this.sprite.url;
        // > Exception from Tracker afterFlush function: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined
        // > TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined

    myImage.onload = function() {
        var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
        ctx.fillStyle = this.sprite.metadata.backColor;
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, scaledSprite.widthDevice, scaledSprite.heightDevice);
        ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
        ctx.drawImage(myImage, 0, 0, scaledSprite.widthDevice, scaledSprite.heightDevice);
    }
};
```

**HTML**

```
<template name="spriteBox">
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="{{ scaledSprite.widthDevice }}" height="{{ scaledSprite.heightDevice }}" style="width:{{ scaledSprite.width }}px; height: {{ scaledSprite.height }}px;">
        This browser does not support HTML5 canvas
    </canvas>
</template>
```

**Iron Router**

```
Router.route('/spriteBox/:_id/:boxsize', {
    name: 'spriteBox',
    template: 'spriteBox',
    waitOn: function() {
        return [
            subs.subscribe('aPix', this.params._id)
        ];
    },
    data: function() {
        var spriteDocument = MyPix.findOne({_id: this.params._id});
        templateData = {
            sprite: spriteDocument,
        }
        return templateData;
    }
});
```

Comment: What happens when you use your rendered code?

Answer (score 1):

One obvious thing wrong with your rendered function is that you can't use {{...}} inside the javascript code. That's just for templates. You need to call the actual functions directly.

Comment: actually it strangely did work for a couple of minutes – not anymore. Even as the template {{}} have been removed. Current code is updated. :/

Answer (score 0):

Based on your new code, you have a new bug:

```
myImage.src= this.sprite.url;
```

should be

```
myImage.src= this.data.sprite.url;
```

Comment: Thanks @tarmes you are right – I had to add brackets though `myImage.src= this.data.sprite.url();`  and it is returning the path now. But I'm still having problems with these `this.data.sprite.metadata.backColor` (trying to grab metadata from the file object) and with the function `scaledSprite` defined in helpers which I am trying to call within the canvas onload function: `scaledSprite.widthDevice`. The syntax seems to be wrong. Both come up as undefined.

Comment: I give up :( – the canvas has been working fine with the script in the html file within the <script> tags. Moving the script out of the html seems to make things more cumbersome.